# Modal gallery won't work when going to subpage from navbar, but works when going directly through URL

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am having a strange problem that I cannot figure out. I made an modal image gallery, and everything works fine when I go directly to the link, that is I type in browser bar http://localhost:3000/gallery and press enter.

Gallery works fine, but when I navigate to the gallery from the home page by clicking the gallery link on the navigation bar, it doesn’t work completely, like the snippet for the modal wouldn't load for some reason.
Theres no file upload, nothing, just static images on the server for now that I want displayed.

Where did I make a mistake doing this?

I've been following this tutorial/jquery plugin to do that:

https://github.com/michaelsoriano/bootstrap-photo-gallery

---

Here are the most important parts I guess:

A static page gallery.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, "Gallery") %>
<h1>Gallery</h1>
<div class="container photos">
  <ul class="first">
      <% @photos.each do |photo|%>
        <li>
          <img src="<%= image_path(photo) %>" style="max-height: 150px !important; min-height: 150px;">
        </li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Here is the part of code that i've put inside application.js that is responsible for the modal to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.first').bsPhotoGallery({
    "classes" : "col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-xxs-12",
    "hasModal" : true
  });
});
```

Here is the link to the gallery that i've placed in my header navbar:

```
<li><%= link_to "Gallery", gallery_path %></li>
```

And in routes.rb i've placed only:

```
get 'gallery' => 'static_pages#gallery'
```

I sense that the js code should probably be manipulated somehow/put somewhere else for it to work both when going directly to the link or when navigating to the gallery from the homepage. But I am out of clues and/or why is it happening like that.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it looks like i found a solution, however I am not sure if that’s the "correct" way to do this, BUT it works!

So what I did, was to change the javascript part to this:

```
jQuery(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  $('ul.first').bsPhotoGallery({
    "classes" : "col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-xxs-12",
    "hasModal" : true
  });
});
```

And now it works both, when accessing the url directly, or when navigating from other pages :)

I hope this will be helpful to someone some day!